# Multiple custom 404 pages

Tags: wordpress, 404, random

Do you have a suggestion on how I can get a random 404 page displayed when a page isn't found.

I use Wordpress and am currently using a custom `404.php` file for displaying a 404 page but what I want is to have three or four different pages that are displayed randomly when a visitor 404s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a dynamic output using PHP inside the `404.php` template.

Effectively you use the `404.php` to include your header, footer and any navigation as per a normal template, and then swap out the normal `loop` and create a block of content that is randomised - e.g.:

```
<? 
$num = Rand (1,4);
switch ($num) { // Here's 4 different examples
 case 1:
 echo "<div>content goes here</div>"; //normal HTML
 break;
 case 2:
 echo $string_output_youve_set_earlier; //HTML in a string
 break;
 case 3:
 include 'random_block_3.php'; //a PHP block
 break;
 case 4:
 get_template_part('random','four'); //Using WordPress's own engine
}
?>
```

Comment: OK, thanks for your help. Can I just use `include `random_block_1.php`;` for each of the cases? Would the name of the file then be `random_block_1.php`, `random_block_2.php` etc.?
Also, if I use WP engine, how does it specify template file to be used?